# Android Opengl-es make transparent background on a texture, how?

Tags: android

I have a texture with a black background.

I d like to make a pixel color key transparency.

My picture is a png file, but the background is not transparent, it is a BLACK(or red or yellow, etc) color.

How can i draw that texture without my background?

this code not work:

```
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
```

this code only work on transparent png's,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That wont work as it looks at the Alpha channel (hence GL_SRC_ALPHA) I would just advise removing the black background and changing it to a transparent one. That way that above code will work and I cant see why you wouldnt want to use the alpha channel

EDIT: Just to note what you are trying to do is known as masking